# cbpFWTabs.js remain on current tab after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have project where I used cbpFWTabs.js to switch between tabs on a single html file , and I have 8 tabs all in all. It works fine but only one problem is that when I click on other tabs and then I need the same tab to remain even when I refresh the page,

What can you suggest for this to happen?, like remain on the same tab even if the page is refreshed of reloaded?.

Thanks

Comment: take a look .... https://stackoverflow.com/a/26902789/4425004