# HTML / JS: How to show selected <li> content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some issues with my codes. I have two pages which are Page A and Page B. At page B, there are 9 main buttons which each button has its own URL. From 9 buttons, there is a button that will redirect to the Page B. Below is the current code for a button at Page A that will redirect to Page B.

Page A.html

```html
<div class="main-enquiry">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1>Send Us Your Enquiry</h1>
        <div class="marginTop">
            <div class="col4 left"><a href="/community/"></a>
                <div class="circleicon"><a href="/community/"></a><a href="/community/"><img src="/App_ClientFile/7ff8cb3f-fbf6-42e7-81da-6db6a0ab2ef4/Assets/i-foundation.png" /></a></div>
                    <h5><a style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: 600;" href="/community/">TG Foundation</a></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After redirect to Page B, there are 3 main tabs at Page B. First tab will be as default, which is the first tab's content will show first. Now, what I want is that after redirect to Page B, I want the third tab as default.

Below is Page B code

Page B.html

```js
( function( window ) {
    'use strict';
    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
    function CBPFWTabs( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }
    CBPFWTabs.prototype.options = {
        start : 0
    };
    CBPFWTabs.prototype._init = function() {
        // tabs elems
        this.tabs = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'nav > ul > li' ) );
        // content items
        this.items = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.content-wrap > section' ) );
        // current index
        this.current = -1;
        // show current content item
        this._show();
        // init events
        this._initEvents();
    };
    CBPFWTabs.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.tabs.forEach( function( tab, idx ) {
            tab.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                self._show( idx );
            } );
        } );
    };
    CBPFWTabs.prototype._show = function( idx ) {
        if( this.current >= 0 ) {
            this.tabs[ this.current ].className = this.items[ this.current ].className = '';
        }
        // change current
        this.current = idx != undefined ? idx : this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length ? this.options.start : 0;
        this.tabs[ this.current ].className = 'tab-current';
        this.items[ this.current ].className = 'content-current';
    };
    // add to global namespace
    window.CBPFWTabs = CBPFWTabs;
})( window );
```

```html
<div class="tabs tabs-style-iconfall">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="icon" href="#section-iconfall-1">First Tab</a></li>
            <li><a class="icon" href="#section-iconfall-2">Second Tab</a></li>
            <li><a class="icon" href="#section-iconfall-3">Third Tab</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Below is the screenshot for page B

[image]

Where the first tab and its contain as default. I want the red circle tab and its content as default.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: change the link in page A to have this fragment at the end `<a href="....#section-iconfall-3" ...`

Comment: @Ma'mounothman can you edit the page A code?

Comment: Which button is the one have the URL? is it any one that links to `/community`?

Comment: @Ma'mounothman the Page B link is /community

Comment: @Ma'mounothman can see my latest question. I already updated

Comment: I added it as answer.

Comment: please provide the javascript code that you have used.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add the fragment like in the following snippet:

```
<div class="main-enquiry">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1>Send Us Your Enquiry</h1>
        <div class="marginTop">
            <div class="col4 left">
                <a href="/community/#section-iconfall-3"></a>
                <div class="circleicon">
                    <a href="/community/#section-iconfall-3"></a>
                    <a href="/community/#section-iconfall-3"><img src="/App_ClientFile/7ff8cb3f-fbf6-42e7-81da-6db6a0ab2ef4/Assets/i-foundation.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <h5><a style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: 600;" href="/community/#section-iconfall-3">TG Foundation</a></h5></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**update: 1**: if you have control over the js file, then you can just edit this chunk and set start to value of `2`:

```
CBPFWTabs.prototype.options = {
  start: 2,
};
```

This is a quick work around, and it should be implemented using `location.hash` instead.

**update 2**:
The following code implementation uses `location.hash` to set the default tab for `cbpFWTabs`, I just added a chunk to check if the tab id is included in the URL hash,

```
...
if (idx === undefined) {
  this.items.forEach(function (el, i) {
    if (el.id === location.hash.substr(1)) {
      tabs.current = i;
    }
  });
}
...
```

Here is the full file implementation, just replace it and then in the `<a>` append `#section-iconfall-3` to the end of `href` attribute so it should link to `community/#section-iconfall-3`

```
/**
 * cbpFWTabs.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright 2014, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
(function (window) {
  "use strict";

  function extend(a, b) {
    for (var key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  function CBPFWTabs(el, options) {
    this.el = el;
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend(this.options, options);
    this._init();
  }

  CBPFWTabs.prototype.options = {
    start: 0,
  };

  CBPFWTabs.prototype._init = function () {
    // tabs elems
    this.tabs = [].slice.call(this.el.querySelectorAll("nav > ul > li"));
    // content items
    this.items = [].slice.call(
      this.el.querySelectorAll(".content-wrap > section")
    );
    // current index
    this.current = -1;
    // show current content item
    this._show();
    // init events
    this._initEvents();
  };

  CBPFWTabs.prototype._initEvents = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.tabs.forEach(function (tab, idx) {
      tab.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        self._show(idx);
      });
    });
  };

  CBPFWTabs.prototype._show = function (idx) {
    let tabs = this;
    if (this.current >= 0) {
      this.tabs[this.current].className = this.items[this.current].className =
        "";
    }
    // change current
    this.current =
      idx != undefined
        ? idx
        : this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length
        ? this.options.start
        : 0;

    if (idx === undefined) {
      this.items.forEach(function (el, i) {
        if (el.id === location.hash.substr(1)) {
          tabs.current = i;
        }
      });
    }

    this.tabs[this.current].className = "tab-current";
    this.items[this.current].className = "content-current";
  };

  // add to global namespace
  window.CBPFWTabs = CBPFWTabs;
})(window);
```

Comment: Still cannot, at Page B (Community), it still display Tab A and the content of Tab A

Comment: are these tabs created using jquery-ui or uiTabs?

Comment: I already edit my question. The code for call the div (content) for first tab

Comment: I dont know where the JS code since I edit the code at CMS. Can you show me on how to see js code at inspect element?

Comment: hmmm, I was about to ask for the Javascript code, but not sure how to check it without URL.

Comment: Can you help to to do the own JS with your style?

Comment: ok I found the site and apparently there is a question here with the same request, the UI tabs used in the CMS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879383/open-a-specific-tab-with-cbpfwtabs, cbpfwtabs library doesn't check for fragments in the URL.

Comment: I already edit my question with JS. I already found it. Please check.

Comment: @PeterDavidson, I updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213017/discussion-between-mamoun-othman-and-peter-davidson).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add window.onload event for page B in which you can put logic to select 3rd tab as default

```
window.onload = function() {
    //your tab selection logic here, put your existing code here which navigates to 3rd tab
}
```